# Getting embedded google docs viewer to work under IE 7,8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, google-docs

Wanted to throw this question out to see if there's been any solutions as the Google Doc viewer is amazing.

Creating an iframe with an embedded Google Docs viewer does not work in IE 7,8.

https://docs.google.com/viewer

Does anyone have a work around?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but didn't think it was acceptable to have to ask users to add the URL to their trusted sites in IE.

Luckily I came across the [following post](http://peterchenadded.herobo.com/gview/index.html):

> The embedded version of Google Docs Viewer (gview) will not load its images correctly if third party cookies are disabled. This problem is an issue for most IE users as by default it will be disabled. Below I provide a work around to this problem for at least until google adds a p3p. The original discussion of the issue can be found at google docs help forum.

I've tried this out and it works in IE8, IE7 and IE6.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried an iframe targeting https://docs.google.com/viewer in IE7 and it is working.

But I have [ChromeFrame](http://code.google.com/intl/de/chrome/chromeframe/) installed in IE - maybe that's the reason it is working for me!

Answer (score 0):

I tested displaying PDFs in Google Viewer with IE8 with following settings.

You may see the solution at http://victoriarange.blogspot.com/2010/07/solution-for-display-problem-of-pdfs-in_24.html